# How can the users access to old contents of data (pages) in my new version of website

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, transfer

I designed a new website, www.AAA.com, and I want save old contents.
On the other hand, I want the users can access to old contents.
new website developed by Umbraco. and old version can be developed by any technology and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. Install the websites into two different directories on your server but set them up like so in IIS:

**Old site as a subdomain or another domain**

`http://www.example.com/` - Umbraco site, as a Website in IIS
`http://legacy.example.com/` - Old site, as Website in IIS with appropriate hostname.
`http://www.example-legacy.com/` - Old site, as Website in IIS with appropriate hostname.

**Old site as a subdirectory**

`http://www.example.com` - Umbraco site, as a Website in IIS
`http://www.example.com/legacy/` - Old site, as a **Virtual Directory** in IIS. Depending on the technology used, but if it's .NET, you'll need to select the **Convert to Application** option so that it's treated as it's own .NET application and not part of the Umbraco site.

One final change needs to be made to the `web.config` of the Umbraco site so that its URL rewriting component ignores parsing the Old site URL when trying to determine what content to show. Otherwise you may get the Umbraco site telling you that the page cannot be found. Append your virtual directory name to the following key:

```xml
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/legacy" />
```

**Final Note regarding Umbraco Site**

Whatever your choice, one thing I'd suggest is to keep the Umbraco site at the root of a domain/subdomain. Older versions of Umbraco had problems if you were to serve them as virtual directories, although I'm not aware if this is still a problem with v6+.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Umbraco but I would recommend you the following:

One of the most used methods is to separate like this.

newest --> www.aaa.com

older than newest  --> www.aaa.com/v1/

older than v2  --> www.aaa.com/v2/

COPY the root of your old site contents to v1 directory on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You could install your new Umbraco site along side the old one in your web server as two separate websites and then make a menu with links in Umbraco for accessing different parts of your old site, And provide a link to the old website in Umbraco for the users to be able to come back.
There may also be the possibility of converting some of your old content into Umbraco. Umbraco's database is not very hard to figure out.